# Как очистить LogCat в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio, android

Раньше все работало отлично. Сейчас заметил: после нажатия кнопки *clear logcat* сообщения лога пропадают на несколько секунд и снова появляется со старыми сообщениями и старым временем.

Как мне избежать возобновления текста лога?

**UPD**
Поначалу думал, что это USB глючит(отключается и подключается снова) и поэтому сообщения и не появляются. Но тоже происходит когда я использую эмулятор, хотя и не всегда это происходит, бывает нормально все удаляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отлично чистится следующим образом: Правой кнопкой мыши по области вывода сообщений в LogCat -> Clear All.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `Run - Edit configurations - Android Application - app - LogCat - Clear log before launch`.

Comment: Пробовал, очищается, а после так же появляется)

Comment: @iamtihonov, стоп! Что именно в логе снова появляется ?
// В логе же еще куча всяких сообщений от операционной системы и сторонних приложений, которые постоянно сыпятся туда. Может рассказать о фильтрации логов и тогда Вы будете знать счастье ?

Comment: Спасибо не нужно). У меня стоит фильтр на мое приложение, когда допустим выполнил действие в логе появляется сообщение,  кроме него больше нет никаких. Ещё раз выполняешь действие, ещё добавилось сообщение, больше никаких. Когда нажимаю clear logcat они пропадают и через несколько секунд возобновляются со старым временем сообщения.

Comment: У меня появляются заново все логи только после повторного подключения смартфона к компьютеру.

Answer (score 0):

В окне LogCat нажимаем "правую кнопку мыши" -> "Clear LogCat"